# "Кто" в придаточном определительном, относящемся к существительному

Tags: грамотная-речь, спп, сложное-предложение, местоимения, придаточное-предложение

*Наш блог будет полезен студентам экономических направлений, **кто** только задумывается о трудоустройстве, а также выпускникам, **кто** уже утроился на работу и столкнулся с типичными проблемами…*

Относительное местоимение используется в качестве союзного слова, по значению сопоставимого с союзным словом "который". Однако во всех знакомых мне предложениях, в которых "кто" присоединяет придаточное определительное, в качестве определяемого слова в главном предложении выступает местоимение "кто‑то", "все", "всякий", но не существительное.

**Вопрос**

Возможно ли употребление **относительного местоимения "кто"** в качестве союзного слова в придаточном определительном, которое относится к **существительному** в главном предложении, как в моём примере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Наш блог будет полезен **тем** студентам экономических направлений, **кто** только задумывается о трудоустройстве, а также выпускникам, **кто** уже утроился на работу и столкнулся с типичными проблемами…*

Это СПП с **определительным придаточным,** отнесенным к существительному. Следует различать два типа таких придаточных: **(1) выделительный и (2)распространительный.**

Сравнить: *Я рассказал это тем друзьям, которым хорошо знаю* (выделительный тип) (2) *Я рассказал это друзьям, которые (они) с интересом меня выслушали* (распространительный тип).

В предложениях (1) **указательное слово факультативно** (его постановка зависит от разных факторов), а в предложениях (2) оно **невозможно** (там нет выделения).

**Заданное предложение по смыслу относится к выделительному типу,** но здесь **указательное слово использовать необходимо**, чтобы отличить выделительное предложение от распространительного.

Сравним: *Наш блог будет полезен  студентам экономических направлений, **которые (все эти студенты)** только задумываются о трудоустройстве, в то время как студенты других направлений  уже давно об этом задумались*.

То есть при отсутствии указательного слова мы не выделяем нужную группу, а рассматриваем всех студентов — **в этом состоит нарушение смысла.**